# High Availability Groups and Fail Over

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, high-availability

I have an active and passive node for HAG's in SQL2012.  The passive node is constantly hit when there is a "READ-ONLY" parameter passed with the connection string.  So, for example, reports would use this type of connection on an everyday basis.

Recently we had a QA environment setup with HAG's as active-active, so NO passive node. From conversing with the DBA's I was told that the difference between the 2 setups (active-active vs active-passive) is that in a fail over situation the active-active setup would allow "READ-WRITE" connections to **continue to work**.

In an active-passive fail over situation any "READ-WRITE" connections would not work because the passive DB would only allow "READ-ONLY" type connections. Further, more tools like SSRS would fail because they can only be setup in one node at a time. Currently we only have it installed in the passive node.  That doesn't make sense because the passive node is one node, which then means we should be able to install it in the active node.  Technically this all sort of makes sense... but then it doesn't.

Isn't one of the **main purposes** of HAG groups to **provide fail over protection** regardless of the setup?  Can anyone shed light on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that either you misunderstood your DBAs or they're not correct.

In an availability group, you have three options with regards to how you want secondary nodes to behave (in order from most to least permissive):

1. Allow any connections
2. Allow only connections that specify application intent as readonly
3. Allow no connections

You also have two options for the primary replica (again in order from most to least permissive):

1. Allow any connections
2. Allow only connecitons that specify application intent as readwrite

What makes this slightly confusing is that this preference is configured *per replica*. That is, you could have the following configuration:

- Node A

  - Primary: Accepts any connection
  - Secondary: Accepts no connections
- Node B

  - Primary: Accepts read-write connections
  - Secondary: Accepts read-only connections

In a failover situation, the role of the primary node is transferred to another node each replica obeys whatever semantics are configured for it. So, in my example above, if the primary is Node A, any application connecting to it will be accepted while only read-only connections will be accepted at Node B. When a failover happens (making Node B the primary), only read-write connections will be accepted at Node B while no connections will be accepted at Node A. I think to avoid confusion, configuring all of the nodes the same way is best. But talk with your DBAs and ask what each node's behavior is in the primary and secondary roles.